# How to find total amount FILTERED BY month in php?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I tried to find total amount for `REPORT_STATUS` IN REPORT table but I dont know how.  I just can count of `REPORT_STATUS` but not by month.

```
$count = "SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(REPORT_STATUS) FROM REPORT WHERE REPORT_STATUS = 1 ) as 
NumberOfReport1, (SELECT COUNT(REPORT_STATUS)  FROM REPORT WHERE REPORT_STATUS = 2) 
as NumberOfAReport2,(SELECT COUNT(REPORT_STATUS)  FROM REPORT WHERE REPORT_STATUS = 3) 
as NumberOfReport3,(SELECT COUNT(REPORT_STATUS)  FROM REPORT WHERE REPORT_STATUS = 4) 
as NumberOfReport4 ";

$result1= mysql_query($count);
```

Comment: Have a look at this perhaps

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040141/how-to-write-an-sql-query-that-counts-the-number-of-rows-per-month-and-year

Answer (score 0):

[GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-modifiers.html) is your friend. Something like this:

```
SELECT month, COUNT(REPORT_STATUS) FROM REPORT WHERE REPORT_STATUS = 1 GROUP BY month
```

Comment: What is it you still can't do? What do you get as result? What do you want? Is there an error? ... Please work on your question.